# SQL query to reference a large list of values in a where xxcolumnxxx in (list of thousands) (i.e. creating a subset that can persist between queries?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, billing, ndc

I need to query a SQL table and pull rows if the value in column NDC_CODE is among my list of values.

The problem is that my list is in the thousands and I'm not sure how best to code this.

I know I can excel-fu/concatenate/copy-paste a 'where' statement together:
where RX_NDC.NDC_CODE in (‘ndc1',’ndc2’,'ndc3',…,’ndc8523’)

My questions are:

1. if I run the code with the where statement as above, manually listing out thousands of values, will use a lot of resources and brick the server?
2. Is it possible to create a "subset" locally that I can reference in the code instead and have this subset persist across multiple queries?
3. I read about creating temporary tables, but I only have read-only access to this database.  Is there some way to create a temporary table locally and reference this in my query?

Comment: You need to tag which DBMS you are using (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, mySQL). Generally it's better to create a temporary table for a list this large and JOIN to that rather than have a huge IN-list - but it will depend on the DBMS as to how you might do that.

Comment: Thanks Fred,  I'm using Sql server management studio.  I'll see if I can dig further into how to create a temporary table.

Comment: Use a table variable or a temp table. If you are using C# you can pass a table-valued parameter.